# RuntimeException (use a converting NullKeySerializer?) while saving entity to neo4j db using spring

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I have a simple project with following entities:

USER

```
@NodeEntity
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity {

@Size(min = 10, max = 10)
@Pattern(regexp = "\\d{10}")
@Property(name="phone")
private String phoneNo;

@Property(name="fname")
@JsonIgnore
private String firstName;

@Property(name="lname")
@JsonIgnore
private String lastName;

@Property(name="activated")
private boolean activated = false;

@Size(min = 2, max = 5)
@Property(name="lang")
private String langKey;

@Size(max = 20)
@JsonIgnore
@Property(name="activationKey")
private String activationKey;

@JsonIgnore
@Property(name="roles")
@Relationship(type="HAS_ROLES", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

//Friends
@Property(name="friends")
@Relationship(type="FRIENDS", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
private Set<User> friends = new HashSet<>();
}
```

AbstractAuditingEntity

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity extends Entity {

@CreatedBy
@JsonIgnore
private String createdBy;

@JsonIgnore
@DateLong
private Date createdDate = new Date();

@LastModifiedBy
@JsonIgnore
private String lastModifiedBy;

@DateLong
@JsonIgnore
private Date lastModifiedDate = new Date();
}
```

ENTITY

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class Entity {

@GraphId
private Long id;
}
```

AUTHORITY

```
@NodeEntity
public class Authority extends Entity {

@NotNull
@Size(min = 10, max = 20)
private String name;

@Property(name="users")
@Relationship(type="HAS_ROLES", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I have removed getter/setters for simplicity. When I try to save the data using repository it throws following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?)
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.executeRequest(EmbeddedRequest.java:181)
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.execute(EmbeddedRequest.java:88)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor.executeSave(RequestExecutor.java:88)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:85)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:44)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:419)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.save(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:203)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
```

During the save, I'm first saving the authority using authority repository and then user information using user repository.

Not able to figure out why is it crashing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.